# Needed Step by Step procedure to create tcp server-client using spring & eclipse

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

I am newbie to Spring framework and Spring Integration. As I went through Spring documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html. I found hard to start. I would like to get the step by step procedure to write an application. Writing from *.xml file, running it, editing the stubs and working on the same.

Although I can see a lot of examples showing TCP /UDP client and server, for a newbie like me, its difficult.

Thanks in advance,
Velman R

Answer (score 1):

See the [tcp-client-server sample app that shows the use of both inbound and outbound gateways to invoke an echo service over TCP](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/tcp-client-server).

It uses the default CRLF to delimit messages; be sure to read the section about (de)serializers in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories).